# What's "EIO: i/o error, write" in node.js and how do I eliminate it?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have a node.js app using elasticsearch to gather error data and notify relevant stack holders. It starts to give me errors lately (no change has made to the code):

```
write EIO
Error: write EIO
    at afterWriteDispatched (internal/stream_base_commons.js:154:25)
    at writeGeneric (internal/stream_base_commons.js:145:3)
    at WriteStream.Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:783:11)
    at WriteStream.Socket._write (net.js:795:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:385:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:367:5)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:307:12)
    at Stdio.write (/project/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/loggers/stdio.js:58:6)
    at Stdio.onError (/project/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/loggers/stdio.js:70:8)
    at Log.wrapper (/project/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4929:19)
    at Log.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Log.error (/project/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/log.js:239:17)
    at checkRespForFailure (/project/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:298:18)
    at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (/project/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:171:7)
    at ClientRequest.wrapper (/project/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4929:19)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

I suspect this has to do with some type of I/O error on the disk. What can I do to eliminate the error? I am using Node.js v14.0.0 and elasticsearch (npm package) 16.7.1.

Comment: You have to provide a little more context, especially how this is related to elasticsearch.

Comment: It's very likely not related to elasticsearch, the only thing is that the fsWrite was called within elasticsearch (no other fs event in the project, actually didn't even require the fs)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be a bug in ElasticSearch's log feature due to the fact it is writing to the stdio synchronously. We will either have to turn off the log or use a third party logger.

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by multiple reasons:

- If you are using Windows is most likely a unicode issue you can fix by executing [chp command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chcp) like this `chcp 850` but if you need Unicode characters then [iconv-lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv-lite) module should help
- When trying to write to a [closed terminal](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/6612)
- Disk [related issues](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3858#issuecomment-64730272), like the disk is full or OS issues... when trying to write the output
- Try to reinstall the modules to the latest version and from scratch since maybe you are using a buggy module or it wasn't installed correctly

Comment: 1. it's a linux (ubuntu) 2. not the case 3. disk is not full, and unlikely to be an OS issue since there is no recent update made 4. i did that, didn't fix it

Comment: Check if the node process has permissions to write, where and what is trying to write you can debug it using node inspect functionality.

Comment: The problem being it the fs feature was not implemented by myself it was part of the elasticsearch...

Comment: Yes I understand, but you still can debug it and you can even modify it manually the module to understand what is the issue even if it's not your module.

Comment: I think I figured it out. ElasticSearch uses a number of sync methods that are not recommended by Node.js. It blocks the process and created these problems. Switching to REST would solve these errors.

Answer (score 0):

Let see if it helps:

If you are on windows, please clear the `%temp%` folder. It helped me when i was running docker container.

Answer (score 0):

Got this kind of error when I was starting a process in a directory, which I had recreated in another terminal tab. Doing `cd .. && cd -` helped. Probably `cd .` or reloading terminal would too.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error with expo 50. I solved it with these steps:

1-Delete `node_module` folder,

2-Run `npm i`,

3-Run `npx expo start --clear`